# Listing the number of properties handled by each staff member

Tags: mysql, sql

Listing the first and last name and the count of properties they own.

Need to also include staff members who do not own any properties but count would be 0.

Here I have the staff members and properties linked with staffNo.

This query displays only the staffs who own a property and how many they own but is not displaying the staffs who do not own any properties

```
SELECT S.branchNo
     , fName
     , lName
     , S.staffNo
     , COUNT(*) AS "count" 
  FROM Staff S
     , PropertyForRent P 
 WHERE S.staffNo = P.staffNo 
 GROUP 
    BY S.branchNo
     , S.staffNo 
 ORDER 
    BY S.staffNo;
```

Comment: move away from implicit join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use implicit joins. [Instead, use Explicit Join based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).
- To get all the staff members, event without any property, you need to use [Left Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx) (with `Staff` table as the leftmost table). This allows all the rows of `Staff` table to come in result (even if there is not matching entry in the `PropertyForRent` table)

Use the following query:

```
SELECT S.branchNo, fName, lName, S.staffNo, 
       IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS "count" 
FROM Staff S 
LEFT JOIN PropertyForRent P ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo 
GROUP BY S.branchNo, S.staffNo 
ORDER BY S.staffNo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to include staff members that have not properties, then think `left join`.  Do you know what that is?  You are using *implicit* joins.  You need to learn proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax.  It is more powerful, and it does what you want.

```
SELECT s.fName, s.lName, COUNT(P.staffNo) AS "count
FROM Staff S LEFT JOIN
     PropertyForRent P 
     ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo
GROUP BY fName, lName
ORDER BY S.staffNo;
```

You should not include extraneous columns in the `SELECT`.  If you want the staff number or other columns, then also include them in the `GROUP BY`.